# patsubst not working in GNU make?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I am using GNU make on Windows 8 to learn about makefiles. The tutorial I am referring is written for Linux, so I am correcting the makefile given as far as I know, e.g. replacing '/' by '\' etc.

My makefile contents are:

```
CC=g++
INCLIST=functions.h
INCDIR=..\include
OBJDIR=.\obj
BINDIR=..\bin
_OBJLIST = main.o
OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)\%,$(_OBJLIST))

all: main.o

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -c -I $(INCDIR) main.cpp -o $(OBJ)
```

I am able to compile the main.cpp manually by

```
g++ -c -I ..\include main.cpp -o .\obj\main.o
```

However, when I run `make`, the output is :

```
g++ -c -I ..\include main.cpp -o .\obj%
```

and the object file is created in the current directory rather than `.\obj` directory and is named `./obj%` instead of required `main.o`. I ran the same setup on Ubuntu and it worked perfectly, can anyone please explain why?

Thanks.. :)

Comment: Backslash is an escape marker, so `\%` is a literal percent sign. Also, `/` works on Windows too.

Comment: `OBJ=$(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)\\%,$(_OBJLIST))` worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good, but seriously, use `/` since that works everywhere (except on DOS, but nobody uses that anymore, right?).

Comment: Yes really, replaced all `\` with `/`s, Thanks! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslash is an escape marker, so \% is a literal percent sign. Also, / works on Windows too.